# java.lang.NullPointerException error in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I cannot seem to escape this error in the debug. No other issues are detected in the problems portion of Android Studio. I do not see any errors in the code, but I'm a newbie.

Code Below:

```
package com.example.bank

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


//Initial User Input bankBalance
            println("Enter Bank Balance")
            var bankBalance: Double = readLine()!!.toDouble()

//Initial User Input withdrawal
            println("Enter withdraw")
            var withdraw: Double = readLine()!!.toDouble()

            while (bankBalance >= 0.0) {
                if (withdraw > bankBalance) {
                    println("Your balance isn't high enough")
                    break
                }

                if (withdraw <= bankBalance) {
                    bankBalance = (bankBalance - withdraw)
                    println(bankBalance)
                    break
                }
                //Looped User Input
                println("Enter Withdraw")
                var withdraw = readLine()
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: this is code for a console application. this is not how you make android apps.

Answer (score 0):

readline() used for java programming, but you are creating an android app whic finally an apk created for android!! so you cannot get user input from terminal!

you can put 2 edittext in your layout and then in your installed app put your inputs inside them